# Zurb Foundation Settings.scss with mixin functions

Tags: zurb-foundation

I uncommented all of the styles from settings.scss and tried to rebuild - it fails due to the settings.scss referencing various mixin functions e.g. color: $isitlight(....)

The default import from app.scss is:

```
@import "settings";
@import "foundation";
```

Obviously with settings being processed first, the referenced mixins (from foundation haven't been loaded yet), hence the error.

However, if I reverse these two statements, the settings.scss don't take any effect, they are overwritten by foundation.

What am I supposed to to get the mixin's workin' with given that the settings.scss needs to be loaded before foundation?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `settings.scss` itself doesn't use any mixins, its the various foundation components included in `foundation.scss`.

For example in `foundation.scss` you will see it import:

```
@import "foundation/components/grid";
@import "foundation/components/accordion";
@import "foundation/components/alert-boxes";
@import "foundation/components/block-grid";"
```

These are the ones that use the mixins. Now we have to find out which one you are using that is requiring a certain mixin.